# Differential backup failing - Ola Hallengren Script

Tags: sql-server-2016, ola-hallengren

So I have installed Ola Hallengren's maintenance solution on our SQL 2016 servers.

I have set the differential backups to take place every evening 7pm and full backup is scheduled for once a week.

I've noticed that differential backups are not being taken.

All the correct permissions have been assigned to the backup drive/folders and having a look through the error logs I keep seeing the same error which is...

('Error creating directory.', 16, 1)

No Azure VM snapshots take place around that time and I've also had a look at VSS and that is disabled.

Any ideas as to why this is not working?

This is happening on all of our SQL servers where the script has been setup not just one specific server.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to say that full backups succeed and only differential have this problem?

Comment: Yes FULL backups succeed but not DIFFERENTIAL

Comment: As a test, you could try creating the `DIFF` folder on the share where the `FULL` folder exists and grant the same permissions on it

Comment: The SQL Engine and SQL Agent need to be able to write to the destination where the backups are going to land. So, if you are using AD service accounts grant the FULL ACCESS to the folders where your backups are occurring. Typically, I grant those AD accounts access to the Local Administrators group. This way I know that the SQL Engine and SQL Agent can do what they need to.